# Retrieve a downloadTicket for an artifact in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to obtain a "publicly accessible" link for the artifact produced during the build process. The [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/artifacts/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) does reference something called a `downloadTicket` but the API call doesn't seem to return anything related. I understand that the download would need to provide the `downloadTicket` through a header, but for now, my question is:

- What call do I need to make, either through the REST API or within a
  build task itself, to get the artifact information, including the
  `downloadTicket`?
- Or option two, is there something else I can to **avoid** uploading
  the file to Azure blob, etc.?

Comment: What's that mean for "`publicly accessible`" here? accessible for all the team members or everyone even he/she is not in a team or group within VSTS (external users or even anonymous users)?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to retrieve the `downloadTicket`?

If you just want to download the artifacts you can use the [REST API - Artifacts - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/artifacts/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to retrieve the `downloadUrl`, then you can **share** and use that URL to download the specific artifact. (*Pleas note that the users need the correct permission to view/download build artifacts*)

```
"downloadUrl": "https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/builds/235/artifacts?artifactName=drop&api-version=5.0-preview.3&%24format=zip"
```

If you want to download the artifacts in build/release process, then you can use [Download Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=vsts) task.

For your option 2, you can create a share location then select `a file share` as the `Artifact publish location` and specify the share location. Thus the artifacts will be published to the shared folder... You can set the share folder to "`publicly accessible`"...

[image]